# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed- There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-keys

I have following table structures:

[image]

This image shows the table structure of ***referral_sources*** table where `(referral_source, agency_id)` is made as **unique key**.

[image]
This image is of ***lead_sources*** table and here `(source, agency_id)` is **unique key**. I am trying to make `(referral_source, agency_id)` of **lead_sources** table as foreign key to `(referral_source, agency_id)` of **referral_sources**.

I have tried following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `lead_sources` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_referral_source` FOREIGN KEY (`referral_source`, `agency_id`) REFERENCES `referral_sources`(`referral_source`, `agency_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

As you can see from both tables that both columns of both tables have same data type, data size and character set. Still I am facing foreign key issue `There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns`.

I have tried to match both columns match with each other, data type, data size, innodb engine, but still not working.

Comment: I suggest you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE referral_sources` to see a better view of the indexes in that table. The error suggests that it doesn't have the index you think it does.

Comment: And in general, don't post screenshots to Stack Overflow where text would be better. This is covered in the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BillKarwin - Your suggestion helped me. Unique key existed there but in reverse order of columns like `(agency_id, referral_source)` and I was creating foreign key in order `(referral_source, agency_id)`. That's why problem. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 1):

When you create FK constraint you may have according indices from both sides.

```
ALTER TABLE `lead_sources` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_referral_source` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`referral_source`, `agency_id`) 
    REFERENCES `referral_sources`(`referral_source`, `agency_id`) 
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

For this statement you must have an index which includes all ref. columns in the same order, i.e. `referral_sources (referral_source, agency_id)`.  The index where `(referral_source, agency_id)` is a prefix (for example, `(referral_source, agency_id, id, created_at)`) is useful too. This index must exist **before** this statement execution.

From the other side of FK the index `lead_sources (referral_source, agency_id)` must exist too. And, as in the above case, ref. columns may be a prefix. But if such index is not present then it will be created automatically.